# Siddhi query for sequential events with conditions

Tags: complex-event-processing, siddhi

I am trying to write a query (not sure if it is possible), something in the form of "If a person has value X their next value cannot be value Y for the next 5 seconds"

My two attempts are:

Sequential:

```
define stream inStream(person string, value string); 
            from every s1=inStream[value == 'X'],  
            s2=inStream[person == s1.person and value == 'Y'] within 5 sec  
            select s2.person  
            insert into outStream
```

This works fine for simple cases, but if I provide input like:

```
"bob", "X"
"steve", "ABC"
"bob", "Y"
```

Then the rule is never triggered for Bob because there is an event from Steve in the middle.

If I try this as a pattern like so:

```
define stream inStream(person string, value string); 
            from every s1=inStream[value == 'X']  
            -> s2=inStream[person == s1.person and value == 'Y'] within 5 sec  
            select s2.person  
            insert into outStream
```

Then it fails on cases like:

```
"bob", "X"
"bob", "Z"
"bob", "Y"
```

because Y is still coming after X within 5 seconds, even though there is a value in between.

My question is, is there either a way to do a sequential query with conditions (e.g. sequential only for the same person) or a pattern with some kind of check to know if another value has been received between X and Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that ended up working for me was using a sequential approach with a partition:

```
define stream inStream(person string, value string);  
            partition with (person of inStream)  
            begin  
            from every s1=inStream[value == 'X'],  
            s2=inStream[value == 'Y'] within 5 sec  
            select s2.person  
            insert into outStream  
            end
```